# convert persian number to english number with str_replace

Tags: php

i wrote this function to convert persian digits to english digits but it returns to me same as input digits(persian).

it contains an array of persian number and i defined an range like persian number and i want to replace persian number with english with str_replace function

```
function convert($string) {
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $num = range(0, 9);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
    return $englishNumbersOnly;
}
```

Comment: Works fine http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19495b7f078be2868ee72cf31f378164fe282170

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $converted=convert('Any String as Input');
   echo $converted;

  function convert($string) {
   $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
   $num = range(0, 9);
   $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
   return $englishNumbersOnly;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print  number persian  you must use font persian..for example you can use WYekan font.

```
<?php
$number =1234;
?>
<p style="font-family: WYekan;"><?php echo $number ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @meykan-jain answer, to parse Arabic and Persian both use this:

```
function parseNumber($string) {
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $arabic = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];
    $num = range(0, 9);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($arabic, $num, $englishNumbersOnly);
    return $englishNumbersOnly;
}
```